# Execute function whenever an initializer List is used

Tags: c#

I have a class that is sometimes created with an initializer list and have to add a new property to it, in most cases it should just contain a reference to itself. For visualisation take the class below.

```
public class Test{
    int number1;
    int number2;
    List<Test> testList;
}
```

With an explicit constructor I would do something like

```
public Test(int num1, int num2){
    number1 = num1;
    number2 = num2;
    testList.Add(this);
}
```

but due to existing code it would be a lot of work to change all occurences and it would be a lot easier to write just one single function that is invoked every time and just inserts the reference into the list.

Microsoft has following on their site:

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties of an object at creation time without having to invoke a constructor followed by lines of assignment statements. The object initializer syntax enables you to specify arguments for a constructor or omit the arguments (and parentheses syntax).

But some kind of function to overload should be there, right?

Comment: What about making multiple constructors?

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve. Object initializers are handled by the language and the compiler, they don't have code on your side. Anyway, if you derive from `List` for example, you can make use of it,

Comment: You should review the concept of list initializer (not initializer-list, that is something from c++)

Comment: @ZorgoZ You can use an object initializer on any writable collection, like lists and dictionaries, without deriving from them

Comment: @Teejay, yes, never said no. But if you want some other logic too, that is not collection-like, you need to derive or somehow make it collection-like or otherwise "compatible" with the initializer logic (https://mariusschulz.com/blog/fun-with-custom-c-collection-initializers).

Comment: The Object should link to itself and possibly to other objects of the same type, its due to some kind of object merging, where i get a new object of the same type but want to know which objects are merged for this special object (so i want to store them in that list) and because a raw object is like an object merged with itself i want to store it inside itself.

Comment: @Brueni so you want to have a list of objects with the reference of the list itself in each of them? Do you have one single list in an application, or you want many?

Comment: Every object should have in the list a reference of itself.

The same mechanism im looking for should be able to perform some logic in the list initializer, maybe checking if values are in a specific range or other things that will provide breaking your code due to wrong values in your objects

Comment: Every single object I want to create should have its unique list containing a reference to itself (later I want to add on some of the objects other object references, when i merged them together so i will always know which objects merged together results in the current object)

Comment: @Brueni you should check the link I have added few comments above. It describing pretty well how the initializer convention works. But beware: initializers are not atomic. They are perfomred as an iteration of basic calls/assignements. That means that things that you would want to check together will arrive separatelly. You might be happy with that, or not. Constructors are there if you need to check initial state at once.

Comment: I checked the link and for that purpose I understand how it works but im not quite sure how it will help me because the Add methods would in the example work for the numbers (seperatly) but would not allow me to set or change values in my overlying object. 
So I assume that there is at least no easy way to check or calculate with the values or I dont get it.
thanks for your effort